# Locally Compact Stone-Weierstrass Theorem

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

**STATEMENT:** Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space, and let $A = C_∞(X)$ be the algebra of continuous real-valued functions on $X$ that vanish at infinity, as above, equipped with the supremum norm. Let $B$ be a subalgebra of A that sep- arates the points of $X$ and is such that for every $x∈X$ there is an $f ∈B$ such that $f(x)\neq 0.$ Prove that $B$ is norm-dense in $A.$

**QUESTION:** So far I have show that I can isometrically embed $B$ into $C(\tilde{X})$, through the map $F$, via the natural extension. I then took the direct sum of $B\oplus \left\{g\right\}$ to satisfy stone-weirstrass theorem. Here is where I am stuck. I don't know how to conclude that this implies that $B$ is norm dense. Some hints would be appreciated.

Comment: $\tilde{X}$ is the one-point compactification of $X$, I suppose? What is $g$? What is the version of Stone-Weierstraß that you learnt in the text? (for compact spaces, I gather)

Comment: Yes $\tilde{X}$ is the one-point compactification. $g$ is the constant map, 1. Real version of stone weirstrass theorem, yes for compact spaces.

Comment: What is the exact formulation for your Stone-Weierstraß?

Comment: Stone–Weierstrass Theorem (real numbers). Suppose X is a compact Hausdorff space and A is a subalgebra of C(X, R) which contains a non-zero constant function. Then A is dense in C(X, R) if and only if it separates points.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $f \in C_\infty(X)$ (that is, $f$ has a continuous extension $\tilde{f}$ to $\tilde{X}$ with $\tilde{f}(\infty) = 0$), and you have a

$$h = b + c\cdot g \in B \oplus \{g\}$$

with $b\in B,\, c \in \mathbb{R}$, and

$$\lVert f - h\rVert_\infty \leqslant \varepsilon,$$

that tells you something about $c$ which in turn yields a useful estimate for

$$\lVert f-b\rVert_\infty.$$

Namely,

$$\varepsilon \geqslant \lVert f-h\rVert_\infty \geqslant \lvert f(\infty) - h(\infty)\rvert = \lvert f(\infty) - b(\infty) - c\cdot g(\infty)\rvert = \lvert c\rvert,$$

and hence

$$\lVert f - b\rVert_\infty = \lVert f - h + c\cdot g\rVert_\infty \leqslant \lVert f-h\rVert_\infty + \lvert c\rvert\cdot \lVert g\rVert_\infty \leqslant \varepsilon + \varepsilon.$$

Comment: Well I can show that $||f-b||_\infty\leq \epsilon+c$, but I still don't see how to get it bounded by just $\epsilon$. It doesn't seem that I can take $b\rightarrow 0$ by our choice of $h$.

Comment: I meant take $c\rightarrow 0$ not $b$ in the previous comment.

Comment: If you evaluate $f - (b + c\cdot g)$ at $\infty$, what's the result?

Comment: Alright I see it now. This would then imply $||f-b||\leq 2\epsilon$.