# Stone Weierstrass Theorem for non compact sets

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, compactness, uniform-convergence

In Rudin (Principles of Mathematical Analysis page 162), the Stone-Weierstrass theorem is proven assuming we have an algebra $\mathscr{A}$ of continuous functions on a compact set $K$ which vanishes nowhere and separates points, and it is clear that the uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$, say $\mathscr{B}$, contains all continuous functions $K \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

---

I am reading a probability textbook that makes use of the following extension for functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ for some $d \ge 1$, in order to prove the uniqueness of characteristic functions:

Suppose that $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra of continuous functions (from $\mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) which vanish at infinity (i.e. $\lim_{\|x\| \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = 0 \quad \forall f \in \mathscr{A}$), separates points, and vanishes nowhere.  Then the uniform closure of $\mathscr{A}$, which we denote $\mathscr{B}$ again, contains all continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ which vanish at infinity.

How do we extend the result from Rudin to this generalized form on $\mathbb{R}^d$?  The proof in Rudin makes very heavy use of the compactness assumption on $K$, so I'm not really sure how to reconcile this.

---

**My ideas (you may ignore these, particularly if you know how to solve the problem):**

Denote $C_0(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R}) \equiv \{f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : f \text{ is continuous, vanishes at infinity}\}$

It is obviously true that if we allow $f \in C_0(\mathbb{R}^d, \mathbb{R})$, $f$ is continuous on any compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$ and $\mathscr{A}$ is an algebra of functions which are continuous on $K$ that satisfy the assumptions required from Rudin so there exists a sequence $f_n \in \mathscr{A}$ which converges to $f$ uniformly on $K$.

However, this does not mean $f \in \mathscr{B}$, since we don't know if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly  $\mathbb{R}^d$, only that the convergence is uniform on $K$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1021245/locally-compact-stone-weierstrass-theorem

Comment: My real analysis background is FAR weaker than what's required to understand that question, as I have no idea what it means to isometrically extend via a natural extension.  Is there a way to extend the theorem stated in Rudin to the one required without what is probably days or weeks of reading for me?

Comment: If you are familiar with the one point compactification, the proof is essentially, "By the stone weierstrass theorem on the one point compactification of $\mathbb{R}^n$, a continuous function $f$ that vanishes at infinity can be uniformly approximated by a continuous function $h$ that has a limit $c$ at infinity. Then the function that is $h$ shifted by $c$, to make it vanish at infinity, also approximates $f$ well"

Comment: @user757173 I'm not really familiar with one point compactification but I read up on it and, to clarify: we just add the point $\infty$ to $\mathbb{R}^d$ and construct a topology $T$ so that $\bar X \equiv \mathbb{R}^d \cup \{\infty\}$ is compact under $T$?  And the limit $c$ is to ensure that $h$ vanishes nowhere so that it is in fact in the algebra defined to be the extension of the continuous functions in $\mathscr{A}$ to the set $\bar X$?  And then we can set $c$ as small as we like so that we can get $\epsilon$ close to $f$ uniformly with functions in $\mathscr{A}$?

Comment: Also, how do we extend a continuous function $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ that vanishes at infinity to a continuous function on $\bar X$?  Do we just define this to be $\bar g(x) \equiv \begin{cases} g(x) \quad x \in \mathbb{R}^d \\ 0  \quad  x = \infty \end{cases}$?   I'm only used to working on metric spaces if I'm completely honest, so I'm not sure how to define a "distance" from a point $x \ne \infty$ to $\infty$, although I imagine the answer is in the definition of the topology $T$ that can be found on wikipedia (just use the neigbourhoods of $\infty$ right?)

Comment: I think there is something wrong with your statement. $\mathscr A$ consists of functions that vanishes nowhere, so function in $\mathscr A$ are either positive or negative, and the limits would be either non-negative or non-positive. Thus something like $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ cannot be in the closure.

Comment: The functions are allowed to be 0.  Vanishing nowhere is a property of the set $\mathscr{A}$, not of the functions themselves.  It means that for each point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, there exists a function $f \in \mathscr{A}$ such that $f(x) \ne 0$.  These functions may attain a value of $0$ at other points though.  Please read the theorem in Rudin; it's incredibly clear there.  Additionally, I've managed to figure out how to use the theorem there to conclude (it's slightly different from my previous comments but pretty much the same).  Thank you @user757173, your comment was very insightful.

Comment: @qp212223 It might be stated in the book but it is indeed not clear what it meant until you stated it. If you have solved your question, please consider posting an answer (that sort of finish this post).